# Why modal won't show from table data when button clicked?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I don't know which the cause but I properly assigned the `data-toggle` and `data-target` to my button. My modal won't show after click the corresponding button that has listener. Any help why it won't show?

```
@section ('content')
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-md-12">
        <table class = "table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Content</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Approver</th>
                    <th>Date Sent</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class = "info">
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="submit"
                                class="btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
                                data-toggle="modal"
                                data-target="#myModal"> Approve</button>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class = "modal fade" id = "myModal">
            <div class = "modal-dialog">
                <div class = "modal-content">
                    <div class = "modal-header">
                        <h4>Confirm Approve</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "modal-body">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: check your console and see if there's any error /warning.

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim I check my console but there's no error or warning. I'm using Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

is there any modal-footer? are you using tables for the layout of just one specific thing?

Comment: Yes. I don't have modal-footer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this for the modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content text-center">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h2 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"> - content- </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        -content-
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        -content-
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```